# I'm using beyondcode laravel-websockets but the service restarts after approximately 1000 concurrent connections. What could be the reason behind it?

Tags: laravel, websocket

We're using `beyondcode laravel-websockets` service, It seems to restart the service every time we get approximately 1000 connections.

I've followed the instructions at https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/faq/deploying.html, and set the soft and hard limits to 50000

The sysad saw messages about SYN flooding in dmesg:
`TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 6001. Sending cookies. Check SNMP counters.`
So he increased `tcp_max_syn_backlog` from 128 to 4096, then to 8192. However, the SYN flooding in dmesg kept occurring and mostly coincided with the service crashing. Next we increased it to something absolutely nuts: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=1000000`

That didn't fix the issue, so next he set net.core.somaxconn = 128, then 4096. (maximum socket backlog)

Looking at the dashboard, I can still see breaks in the server, regardless of what we've tried.

I'm struggling to figure out where the problem is - I've tried hammering the websocket with thor, and the http service (eg the auth) with siege, but I haven't been able to break it with either.

According to the documentation, it should be able to handle 15,000 concurrent connections: https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/faq/scaling.html.

Has anyone experienced this? If so, what have you done to solve it? Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get any answers there, so thought I'd widen my reach. There was something about installing ev or event pecl plugin, but I've got no idea what config would be required to enable it. Assuming it doesn't just work by magic.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in PHP's error log or Laravel's `storage\logs`? Maybe it has some info?

Comment: I don't have access to the server logs but will ask someone who does. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think I was wrong - I suspect now that it isn't restarting, but instead is mostly just failing to write to the statistics table. We're getting a lot of errors like this:

`Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException: Exception 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException' with message '' in /var/www/html/websockets/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php:119` and the stack trace.

Comment: Also, it sometimes takes the application many times to connect to the socket server. I can see one instance where it gives a "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established" 8 times, then an Error during WebSocket handshake", another 15 times it closed, and then it's connected.